# Can I install only Grub into a mainly Windows installation?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Other questions here have been talking about Windows + Ubuntu dual boot. Mine is about Windows + Windows

I'm hoping to have a Laptop run GRUB on boot, so I can choose which version of Windows I'm using

Currently, the laptop is not seeing both at the same time, but can be swapped using a convoluted process of restarts and holding keys while booting. Grub is so much easier to use

I'd gladly just install Ubuntu here and be done with it, but this isn't my laptop, and the owner hopes to not need to handle a 3rd OS

Comment: Windows only puts boot files into one partition if BIOS or only one ESP if UEFI. And manual grub only requires user to manually configure Windows boot stanza. But there may be work arounds, but those are Windows questions as non-standard install of Windows. This is an Ubuntu question & answer site, so this question will be closed soon.

Comment: Install Ubuntu in same BIOS/UEFI mode as Windows, then delete the Ubuntu root partition.

Comment: How is this an Ubuntu problem?

Comment: @mook765: Sorry, I was a little unclear. By **delete the Ubuntu root partition** I meant **everything except the boot and EFI folders**, (which I usually keep on their own partition). I have just tested this and can boot Windows fine using Ubuntu's GRUB, with the rest of Ubuntu deleted.

Comment: @user68186, I apologize, but while my problem could be solved by other methods, I was hoping to use GRUB specifically. Thus my thoughts on asking in AskUbuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using GRUB from Ubuntu to Boot Multiple Windows Installations

- Create a 10GB EXT4 partition on the Windows disk for Ubuntu using Windows Disk Management .
- Use Live USB to install Ubuntu to it's partition using **Something else** option. Use same BIOS or UEFI mode as Windows is installed in. All OS must be the same mode.
- Select Windows disk for bootloader location.
- Do not select any Windows partitions for formating.
- Complete installation.
- Boot computer using new Ubuntu install.
- Run `sudo update-grub`, shut down.
- Boot computer using Live USB.
- In terminal run `sudo -H nautilus`.
- Delete all of Ubuntu except boot and EFI folders.
- Edit /Boot/grub/grub.cfg to remove unwanted menuentries.

Computer should now boot into GRUB menu with Windows OS options.

I think most people prefer **EasyBCD** for booting multiple versions of Windows. https://neosmart.net/Download/Register

Comment: This feels like best set of steps. I'll try it out in a few hours after work, and I'll give a heads up after

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few options for this.
I will give some pointers, and refer to the original posts.
It is great for the benefit of the community (so others also take advantage of this Q&A) if you provide feedback on what you try and what you get.

1. [Grub4DOS](https://sites.google.com/site/grubdos/), see also [1](https://sourceforge.net/projects/grub4dos/), [2](http://grub4dos.sourceforge.net/).
2. Via [rufus + `grub-install`](https://dev.to/lquenti/using-grub-without-linux-for-windows-7-10-dual-boot-configuration-45pf).
3. With [grub for windows](https://www.aioboot.com/en/install-grub2-from-windows/).
4. With [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/). See also [3](https://superuser.com/questions/381285/how-to-install-grub-from-inside-windows-7).
5. With [Grub2Win](https://sourceforge.net/projects/grub2win/).

Comment: Mr Cameron provided steps. I'll try his option first, before I read through yours